# Altitude from two sides of a triangle add up to the other altitude, find the perimeter

Tags: geometry, triangles

This was a question from a high school math olympiad I couldn't answer, it is low level to most other stuff here but I would appreciate some help.

There is a triangle with integer side lengths X, Y and 20, with X>Y>20. Let x, y, and h be the altitude of each side respectively. If x + y = h, find the perimeter of the triangle.

Comment: Hello and Welcome To Mathematics StackExchange. We generally don’t care about low/high level, but what we do care about is you making us solve problems for you. This is not a do-the-work-for-me community. Here you are generally expected to show your work and how you would start the problem. Here are few links:

Comment: 1. [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)2. [How to format math here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) 3. [Don’t say “I have no clue where to start](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27923/how-to-prevent-no-clue-questions) 4. [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) (use the syntax for mathmode only).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the help! Sorry about the low effort question, I'd edit the post but it's a bit redundant now. I'll take more care in writing my questions in the future.

Comment: The basic formulas for a triangle with sidelengths $a,b,c$ and altitude lengths $h_a,h_b,h_c$ is: area of triangle = $\frac12 h_a∗a=\frac12 h_b∗b=\frac12 h_c∗c$ giving constraint $\frac2a+\frac2b=\frac2c$, reducing your issue to solving a system of two equations with two unknowns.

Answer (score 1):

There is something not very clear about the statement of the problem. The information is insufficient to get a unique value of the perimeter.

Indeed, computing the area in $3$ ways and using that $h=x+y$, we get, after simplifying, that
\begin{equation}
20(x+y)=xX=yY. (a)
\end{equation}

These are essentially two equations with four unknowns and while we don't need to explicitly compute $X$ and $Y$, just their sum (since the perimeter $P=20+X+Y$), this is still insufficient for a unique solution. This is quite intuitive because at best we could reduce to three unknowns, i.e., $x,y,X+Y$ instead of $x,y,X,Y$.

Now, doing some substitutions in $(a)$, we can get for example that $X=20(1+\frac{y}{x})=20(1+\frac{X}{Y})$ and $Y=20(1+\frac{x}{y})=20(1+\frac{Y}{X})$, so we can easily express the perimeter in terms of, for example, $x$ and $y$ as $P=60+20(\frac{x}{y}+\frac{y}{x})$ and this tells us that the perimeter satisfies $P\geq 100$ through a trivial inequality.

Now let's show this information does not uniquely determine the perimeter. We'll consider the perimeter as a function of the side length $Y$ and write $P(Y)$. For a triple of numbers $(X,Y,20)$ to correspond to a triangle, the sides need to satisfy the triangle inequality. This together with the assumption that $X>Y>20$, boils down to $20<Y<X\leq Y+20$. We can express $X$ from $(a)$ as $X=\frac{20Y}{Y-20}$.

Plugging this in we obtain $Y^2-20Y<20Y\leq Y^2-400$ and dealing with the degree two equations we find that
\begin{equation}
Y\in [10+10\sqrt{5},40). (b)
\end{equation}

For each $Y$ as prescribed by $(b)$ we can take $X=\frac{20Y}{Y-20}$ to get the perimeter $P(Y)=20+\frac{Y^2}{Y-20}$. Note that as long as we pick
\begin{equation}
\frac{x}{y}=\frac{Y-20}{20}, (c)
\end{equation} we will automatically satisfy $(a)$ and additionally note that we can write the area of a triangle as a function of $Y$ using Heron's formula,
\begin{equation}
A(Y)=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\sqrt{P(Y)\big(P(Y)-40\big)\big(P(Y)-2Y\big)\big(P(Y)-\tfrac{40Y}{Y-20}\big)}. (d)
\end{equation}

So equating $yY=2 A(Y)$ we can find the correct value of $y$ and therefore of $x$ (using $(c)$). In other words any choice of $Y$ satisfying $(b)$ will give rise to a triangle that fulfills the assumptions of the problem.

Finally, note that $Y=33$ and $Y=35$ both satisfy $(b)$, but $P(33)=20+\frac{1089}{13}\cong 103.77$ and $P(35)=20+\frac{1225}{15}\cong 101.67$.

In fact, the function $Y\mapsto P(Y)$ is strictly decreasing on the domain $[10+10\sqrt{5},40)$, so the best we can say is that $P(40)<P\leq P(10+10\sqrt{5})$ and computing this out implies $100<P\leq 60+20\sqrt{5}\cong 104.72$.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! Now that I think of it, I'm pretty sure the question also stated that all sides were integers, sorry for leaving that out. What I did then was find: 20h/X +20h/Y = h, giving 20/X +20/Y = 1. I then plugged in integers keeping in mind the triangle inequality theorem and found 20/36 + 20/45 =1. I have no idea if this is right, or the only solution, and was looking for a more elegant solution but I can't find it.

Comment: Oh, well then you can simply check for $Y\in\{33,34,35,36,37,38,39\}$ if $X$ is also an integer. I think that by trying it out, this only works when $Y=36$ and then $X=\frac{20Y}{Y-20}=45$, giving you a perimeter of $P=20+36+45=101$.

Comment: Again, thanks so much!